# Embossing an Image

Tags: image, scheme, iteration

I've been working on an image-emboss procedure with my class' special image ADT, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have included my recently edited code and the image procedures that I have been using for the problem. If you have a couple minutes to sit through the explanation, you might find this type of image editing interesting.

```
  (define bound
      (lambda (n)
        (cond
          [(<= n 0) 0]
          [(>= n 255) 255]
          [else n])))
```

Bound takes an integer and crops values outside the range 0 to 255, inclusive, to the endpoints.

```
(define boost
  (lambda (x)
    (bound (+ 127 x))))
```

Boost takes an integer, adds 127 to it, and then bounds the result. The number 127 is the focus of boost because we will use boost to boost colors and 127 is half the range of a color component.

```
(define image-emboss
  (lambda (img)
    (define emboss
      (lambda (r c)
        (let ([a (image-ref img r (add1 c))]
              [b (image-ref img (add1 r) (add1 c))]
              [c (image-ref img (sub1r) (add1 c))]
              [d (image-ref img r (sub1 c))]
              [e (image-ref img (sub1 r) (sub1 c))]
              [f (image-ref img (add1 r) (sub1 c))])
          (if (or (< r 0) (< c 0))
              img
              (make-image r c (boost (- (+ a b c) d e f)))))))
  (emboss r c)))
```

"In an embossed image, the color of each pixel is computed from six of the pixels neighbors in the original image. Each color component of the embossed pixel is obtained by adding the corresponding components of the three pixels in the row directly above it and subtracting the components from the three pixels in the row directly below it, and then applying boost to the result."

[image: Image of pixels needed]

I've tried to create image-emboss: it takes an image and returns an embossed version of the image. Pixels along the perimeter are unchanged. This proc is supposed to use make-image and image-ref.

Image-rows takes an image and returns the number of rows in the image.

```
(define image-rows
  (lambda (img)
    (cond
     [(image? img 1 1) (vector-length (img))]
     [else
      (error 'image-rows (format "~a is not an image" img))])))
```

Image-cols takes an image and returns the number of columns in the image.

```
(define image-cols
  (lambda (img)
    (cond
     [(image? img 1 1) (if (zero? (vector-length (img)))
                           0
                           (vector-length (vector-ref (img) 0)))]
     [else
      (error 'image-cols (format "~a is not an image" img))])))
```

Image-ref takes an image, row-index, and column-index, and returns the pixel.

```
(define image-ref
  (lambda (img r c)
    (if (not (image? img 0 0))
        (error 'image-ref "first argument is not an image"))
    (if (and (integer? r) (<= 0 r (- (image-rows img) 1)))
        (if (and (integer? c) (<= 0 c (- (image-cols img) 1)))
            (vector-ref (vector-ref (img) r) c)
            (error 'image-ref (format "~a is an illegal index" c)))
        (error 'image-ref (format "~a is an illegal index" r)))))
```

Make-image takes rows, cols, and a procedure.

```
(define make-image
  (lambda (rows cols . args)
    (let ([gen-proc
           (cond
            [(null? args) (lambda (i j rows cols) black)]
            [(not (null? (cdr args)))
             (error 'make-image "too many arguments")]
            [(color? (car args)) (lambda (i j rows cols) (car args))]
            [(procedure? (car args)) (car args)]
            [else (error 'make-image (format "unknown fill: ~s" 
                                             (car args)))])])
      (let ([img (make-vector rows)])
        (let loop ([i 0])
          (when (< i rows)
            (vector-set! img i 
                         (let ([row (make-vector cols)])
                           (let loop ([j 0])
                             (when (< j cols)
                               (vector-set! row j (gen-proc i j rows cols))
                               (loop (+ j 1))))
                           row))
            (loop (+ i 1))))
        (lambda () img)))))
```

The way I am testing this is by dloading an image and defining it in the repl, then drawing the image using a procedure created by my prof.

Anyways. I think my code is close to being correct, but I am really not sure how to correct it. If anyone has a hint/ better explanation that will help me figure this out, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure what other issues you're seeing, one thing that strikes me off-the-bat is the `image-emboss` function doesn't seem to have the correct evaluation flow at the moment.  From what I see, when you are calling `image-emboss`, you pass it an image, at which point it evaluates the lambda which evaluates the lambda for `emboss`, and then calls `emboss` with the values `r` and `c` ... but you haven't defined `r` and `c` in the environment (that is the environment-frame created by the `image-emboss` lambda) that `emboss` is being calling inside of.  How then can the scheme interpreter evaluate the two symbols `r` and `c` for a proper call to the lambda defined by `emboss`?

I would think at the very least your call to `emboss` inside of `image-emboss` should look more like `(emboss (image-rows img) (image-cols img))` rather than `(emboss r c)`.  A call to `(emboss (image-rows img) (image-cols img))` has symbols that can all be evaluated in the environment-frame defined by `image-emboss` ... `(emboss r c)` on the other-hand doesn't.

I'm not sure what other issues you're having since you haven't described any of the actual errors you're getting, or what the results may look like if they're getting mangled.  But again, I would say the code-error I've described is at least one major issue you must be encountering when using the `image-emboss` function.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: This actually did help me a lot. I haven't worked with image procedures much so I was kind of lost on this problem. It's pretty funny looking back at old posts on SO, realizing how much programming you can actually learn in a week or two.

Comment: Anyways, what I should have done was defined two loops, r and c, as (sub1 (image-rows image)) and (sub1 (image-cols image)). Then, when r and c are >= 0, proceed to emboss the image and sub1 from the r and c through each iteration.